# Java Detect Whether Float Is Positive or Negative

Tags: java, android, numbers, floating-point

I'm working with Android gestures and the onFling method. There are two float variables get passed velocityX and velocityY. Theses can either be 0.0, positive or negative. Obviously the 0.0 is easy to detect but how to I detect whether it's a positive or negative float.

I found some code for int and double but nothing relating to float specifically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried `<` and `>`?  These operators are used for that sort of thing...

Comment: Yeah was just wondering if there was a built in function. I say someone talking and exampling a build in thing for DOUBLE's

Comment: Javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

The built-in function would be the <name>.compareTo(Double anotherDouble)

Answer (score 3):

Just compare with 0.0. like this:

```
var x = 0.01;
var y = -0.01;
if (x > 0.0) { /* positive */ }
if (y < 0.0) { /* negative */ }
```